# How to refresh the Labels and other controls inside the GroupBox/Panels inside a Form in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, refresh, groupbox

I'm designing a C# application where I have a groupbox showing OS and RAM related information. 
I designed it using the controls - labels put together in a Groupbox showing RAM related information.

I have a Refresh button which when clicking should display % of RAM used currently.

For this, I need the label (and also few other labels) inside the groupbox to **refresh and re-compute the value.**

How do i do this? I tried all below in the RefreshButton_Click event but nothing works:

```
label1.Refresh(); 

GroupBox1.Refresh(); 

Form1.Refresh(); 
Form1.Invalidate(true); 

Panel1.Refresh();
```

Pls help in this as I do not think reloading an entire form would an efficient solution.

Comment: if you want to recalculate then you need to call method which will recompute alll information. if you want to clear all labels in groupbox use groupbox.Controls collection and clear text properety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refreshing won't do anything but display the same assigned value. You must set the new calculated values to your controls inside your RefreshButton_Click handler:

```
var myNewValue = CalculateNewValue();
label1.Text = myNewValue;
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Create a class containing the properties that you want to display and implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for all of your properties. Then use Data Binding to bind your object to your controls on your form. The controls will update automatically when the properties of your object changes.

See [Using the INotifyPropertyChanged functionality](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/208833-using-the-inotifypropertychanged-functionality/) or google [INotifyPropertyChanged DataBinding WinForms c#](http://www.google.com/search?q=INotifyPropertyChanged%20DataBinding%20WinForms%20c#).

Answer (score 0):

In winforms you do not refresh entire forms, use just trigger events that update parts of the forms. I have included below the way of doing this. Basically you need a computational function and you need to update the label by setting the text with the output of that function. You will need to add as many functions as needed.

Ultimatly you will want to create a calculation class since you will want to seperate your UI from your calculations.

Here is an example:

```
private void RefreshButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Assuming label1 is for the Ram
    label1.text = getRamString();
}

private string getRamString()
{
    float ramValue = //Calculate the RAM
    return string.Format("{0}%", ramValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest, but not too elegant way is to loop all controls in desired group box. Sample code

```
        // Got group box control
        Control[] controls = Controls.Find("groupBox1", false);

        // List all elements in group box
        foreach(var c in ((Control)controls[0]).Controls)
        {
            // Update in case it is label
            if( c.GetType().ToString().EndsWith("Label") )
            {
                ((Label)c).Text = "label...";
            }
        }
```